# Can not Finish Scorm on Android

Tags: android, webview, scorm

I have scorm offline player, it can play the scorm. But when I want to finish the scorm, it did not respond. I have to try to debug with google chrome web view debugger for android. But I can not find the issue. I also have been try in emulator & device but it has the same issue.
The only log that shown is "Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread"